# Android MediaMux & MediaCodec too slow for saving video

Tags: android, video-capture, android-mediacodec, mediamuxer

My Android app does live video processing using OpenGL. I'm trying to save it to video using MediaMuxer and MediaCodex.

The performance it not good enough. Each cycle the screen is updated, and it is saved to file. The screen is smooth, the video file is horrible. By this I mean major motion blur when it changes quickly and the frame-rate appears to be 1/2 or 1/3rd of what it should be.

It seems to be a limitation due to clamping of settings internally. I can't get it to spit out a video with a bit rate greater than 288KBPS. I think it is not clamping the requested parameters because there is no difference in frame rate for 1024x1024, 480x480, and 240x240. If it was having trouble keeping up, it should at least improve when the number of pixels drops by a factor > 10.

The app is here : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.matthewjmouellette.snapdat.

I would love to post a code sample, but my program is 10K lines of code, with a lot of relevant code just for this problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I've tried like 10+ different things. I'm out of ideas right now. I wish I could just save the video uncompressed, the hard-drive should be able to keep up with a small enough image and medium fps.

It seems to be that the encoding method just doesn't work for my video. The frames differ to much, to try to "move" one part of the frame, as a sort of encoding. Instead I need full frames throughout. **I am thinking something along the lines of M-JPEG would work really well.** JPEGs tend to take 1/10th the size of a bitmap. It should allow a reasonable size, with almost no processing power required by the CPU, since it is image compression not video compression which we are doing. I wish I had a good library for this.

Comment: What device are you testing on?  What version of Android?  Do you see equivalent behavior from Grafika's "Show + capture camera"?  (https://github.com/google/grafika)

Comment: Samsung Galaxy S4. I'm using Android 4.3. No, I haven't tried that app, I will do when I have time.

Comment: I just noticed that under "Record GL app" he says "#3 doesn't work yet", which refers to saving the results to file (I think). But I will test when I have time!

Comment: please check this: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-inde-media-pack-for-android-tutorials-video-capturing-for-opengl-applications

Comment: "#3 doesn't work yet" refers to using `glBlitFramebuffer()`, which is broken on the devices I've tested.  Saving the results to file works fine.  My guess at your app's problem would be incorrect presentation time stamps, which on some devices can cause dropped frames and low-quality output, so check the values you're submitting with the frames.

Comment: @Marlon, the site is down...

Comment: Strange, i can reach it without any problem. Please try to google: Intel® INDE Media Pack for Android* Tutorials - Video Capturing for OpenGL* Applications. It gives a way to capture GL scenes to mp4 files

Comment: Aww. It works in IE, but not in firefox.

Comment: any progress with it?

Comment: I've been trying a libary JCodec. Some issues at the moment. The timestamps are all wrong, but that is whatever. The video output is great, but the performance in the app is total garbage. Like 100 x 200 "Video" is probably the most I can do ATM. I think that could be fixed by changing the encoding format.

Comment: I have added more details to the question.

Comment: The Intel Media Pack looks good, but it also looks identical to the first method I tried. I'm also worried about the version requirements. Since they switch context, I am thinking I will need Android 4.3 minimum, while I am currently requiring only 4.03.

Comment: I'll keep trying with JCodec for now, if it doesn't work, then I'll try Grafika, and the Intel library. But would u guys know how to do M-JPEG encoding? I'm pretty sure that is the answer that I need! It's not hard to encode an image to JPEG in Android, I would even write the file headers myself if I knew how to do it.

Comment: With h.264 encoder, which actually acts on GPU realtime processing is achievable i think. MJPEG encoding will require CPU involving what will result in higher CPU usage and greater times depending on picture resolution and memory coping from opengl surface to memory buffer

Comment: My app is pretty much maxing the GPU already, in order to do the filtering that it does. It would probably be better to put the work on the CPU, I can throw that onto another thread (which I have already done with my 2nd attempt). A phone will have 2 or 4 CPU cores, but only 1 GPU.

The work required to "extract" the image from the GPU is very doable, I have tested that out already, and it doesn't impact performance.

I think I will try MJPEG compression next (3rd attempt). It is very easy to encode the YUV data in android, I just need to know what headers to throw in.

Comment: My underlying thoughts are that JPEG compression will be a lot less total work, then having to do Video Encoding. So if the GPU can manage to do video encoding involving comparing frames, than the CPU can manage to simply compress the images into individual JPEGs.